# JavaScript Object / Classes

Tags: javascript

Difference between two different type of JavaScript classes shown below:

**First One :**

```
 var apple = new function() {
    this.type = "macintosh";
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    };
}
```

**Second One :**

```
 var apple = ({
      type:'macintosh',
      color:'red',
      getInfo: function() {
       return type +' '+ color + 'apple';
      }
});
```

Both are defined in .js files.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: My question . Both are different way to represent apple class or both are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first one is a class you can create objects from it

```
var test = new apple();
```

second is object you can use its members and methods

Comment: No, it isn't. The use of the `new` keyword immediately calls the function expression as a constructor and assigns an object to `apple` which is not a function. Your code throws an error. https://jsbin.com/baximonanu/1/edit?js,console